# Date scale with bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I tried to create bar chart with d3, everything is ok, but I haven't data for weekends for my X axis, and naturally I have some spaces between bars.

Who knows how to get rid of them?

[spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlvrI.jpg)

How I render bars

```
return values(stack).map((d, index) =>
          <rect key={index} clipPath="url(#gf)"
             className={`bar ${d.y < 0 ? 'negative' : 'positive'}`}
             style={{fill: color(stack.label)}}
             data-legend={stack.key}
             x={x(d.x) + ((xScale.rangeBand() * seriesIndex) / data.length)}
             y={d.y < 0 ? _yScale(0) : _yScale(d.y)}
             width={width <= 0 ? 2 : width}
             height={Math.abs(_yScale(d.y) - _yScale(0))}
          ></rect>
);
```

Variables:

```
this.state = {
  ...
  x: d3.time.scale(),
  y: d3.scale.linear(),
  ...
};

x.range([0, this.xScaleWidth])
   .domain(this.calculateDomain(data, 'x'));

const xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(values(stack).map(e => { return e.x; }))
   .rangeRoundBands([0, this.xScaleWidth], 0.4, 0);

const width = xScale.rangeBand() / data.length;

const _yScale = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain(yDomain)
   .range([this.props.dim.height, 0])
   .nice();
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: If your problem is how to represent that missing data. Take a look to this: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/69738/design-pattern-to-display-missing-data-in-line-bar-chart-of-a-daily-data-feed